# How to delete minority rows from a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, delete-row

I have a data frame. For all possible combination of values in the first two columns, I would like to delete those rows for which the number of rows smaller than 100.

For example, there are 5 rows in which in the first column we have "A" and "B" in the second column. All these rows I would like to delete from the data frame. There are 110 rows in which the first and the second rows contains "C" and "D", respectively. These rows I do not want to delete since 110 > 5.

What is the most elegant and fast way to do that?

This is the solution that I have at the moment:

```
gr = df.groupby(['L_ID', 'P_ID'])
for group in gr.groups:
    df_tmp = gr.get_group(group)
    n_vals = len(df_tmp)
    if n_vals < min_n:
        df = df[(df['L_ID'] != group[0]) | (df['P_ID'] != group[1])]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`filter()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#filtration) method:

```
# test data
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('AAABB'), 'b':list('BBBAA'), 'c':range(5)})
>>> df1
   a  b  c
0  A  B  0
1  A  B  1
2  A  B  2
3  B  A  3
4  B  A  4

>>> df1.groupby(['a','b']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2)
   a  b  c
0  A  B  0
1  A  B  1
2  A  B  2
```

#### update

Looks like this method is not working when there're more columns:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('AAABB'), 'b':list('BBBAA'), 'c':range(5), 'd':range(5)})
>>> df1
   a  b  c  d
0  A  B  0  0
1  A  B  1  1
2  A  B  2  2
3  B  A  3  3
4  B  A  4  4
>>> df1.groupby(['a','b']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2094, in filter
    if res:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Here's a solution:

```
>>> df1.groupby(['a','b']).filter(lambda x: len(x['c']) > 2)
   a  b  c  d
0  A  B  0  0
1  A  B  1  1
2  A  B  2  2
```

You can also use [`transform()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#transformation):

```
>>> df1[df1.groupby(['a','b'])['c'].transform(lambda x: len(x) > 2).astype(bool)]
   a  b  c  d
0  A  B  0  0
1  A  B  1  1
2  A  B  2  2
```